# Issue converting from JSON to POJO using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a JSON REST endpoint response and I wanted to get the value of `hotelNbr` from it. How do i do it ?

```
{
  "found": [
    {
      "hotelNbr": 554050442,
      "hotelAddress": "119 Maven Lane, New Jersey",
    }
  ],
  "errors": []
}
```

I am using the below code to get it but it fails in below mentioned line:

```java
public List<Hotel> RDS_POST_HotelDetails(String HotelName, String sUrl) throws Exception, IOException {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

            // Create your http client
            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

            // Create http Put object
            HttpPost ohttppost = new HttpPost(sUrl);

            // Message Body

            StringEntity input = new StringEntity(

                    "{\"hotelNbr\":[\""+HotelName+"\" ]}"
                    );

            // Set content type for post
            input.setContentType("application/json");

            // attach message body to request
            ohttppost.setEntity(input);

            // submit request and save response
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(ohttppost);

            // Get response body (entity and parse to string
            String sEntity = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                List<Hotel> hotelobject = new ArrayList<Hotel>();

                // Create a type token representing the type of objects in your json response
                // I had to use the full class path of TYPE because we also have a  Type class in our project
                java.lang.reflect.Type cType = new TypeToken<List<Hotel>>() {
                }.getType();

                // Convert to Array object using gson.fromJson(<json string>,
                // <type>)
                hotelObject = gson.fromJson(sEntity, cType); // I am getting error here 

                String hotelNumber = hotelObject.get(0).getFound().get(0).getItemNbr().toString();

}
```

Please find the Hotel.java class below

```
package com.hotels.company;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Hotel {

    @SerializedName("found")
    @Expose
    private List<Found> found = null;
    @SerializedName("errors")
    @Expose
    private List<Object> errors = null;

    public List<Found> getFound() {
        return found;
    }

    public void setFound(List<Found> found) {
        this.found = found;
    }

    public List<Object> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

    public void setErrors(List<Object> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

}
```

Please find `Found.java` class below :

```java
package com.hotels.company;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Found {

    @SerializedName("hotelNbr")
    @Expose
    private Integer hotelNbr;
    @SerializedName("hotelAddress")
    @Expose
    private String hotelAddress;

    public Integer getHotelNbr() {
        return hotelNbr;
    }

    public void setHotelNbr(Integer hotelNbr) {
        this.hotelNbr = hotelNbr;
    }

    public String getHotelAddress() {
        return hotelAddress;
    }

    public void setHotelAddress(String hotelAddress) {
        this.hotelAddress = hotelAddress;
    }

}
```

I tried finding some examples in StackOverflow questions but didn't get solution for mine. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is the error stack?

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you are parsing is not well formatted..

There is a comma after "hotelAddress" remove that

Correct JSON would be:

```
 {  
   "found":[  
      {  
         "hotelNbr":554050442,
         "hotelAddress":"119 Maven Lane, New Jersey"
      }
   ],
   "errors":[ ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple of issues:

1. Json is not valid. Observe there is a comma at the end of `"hotelAddress": "119 Maven Lane, New Jersey",`. Remove it.
2. You are trying to deserialize the json into `List<Hotel>`, but the json mentioned is not a list. Either update the json or deserialise it into `Hotel` object instead of `List`.

Comment: I removed the , from the JSON but still getting same issue